# Why wont eclipse generate build.xml

Tags: xml, eclipse, ant, javafx

Im using e(fx)clipse and after following the steps outlined here http://code.makery.ch/java/javafx-8-tutorial-part7/
Nothing happens when you click "Generate ant build.xml".... can anyone help here? If no one has a clue can someone help me manually get this done

This is the settings on the build.fxbuild
[image: build.fxbuild used by e(fx)clipse]

And I am using eclipse 4.4

```
!SESSION 2014-10-18 18:46:48.482 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.8.0_20
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_NZ
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.fx.ide.java6 4 0 2014-10-18 18:46:49.497
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.fx.ide.java6 [221]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version>=1.3)(!(version>=1.8)))"

at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
at     org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 1 0 2014-10-18 18:46:54.133
!MESSAGE Nothing to merge for "platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.e4.tools.emf.ui/fragment.e4xmi"

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 1 0 2014-10-18 18:46:54.137
!MESSAGE Nothing to merge for "platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.e4.tools.emf.ui/fragment.e4xmi"
```

The log pops up with this error when I hit generate

I suppose I should note that I tried to create an exe with netbeans too but when run it would give me an "error in man class" but there's nothing wrong with it when I run it through the IDE...

Comment: The value in "Application class" looks wrong or didn't you follow Java conventions where classes start with an upper case.

You can also check the error log of Eclipse to see if something went wrong

Comment: I think I have a forum post going with you too XD should we just continue on the forums and edit here with more details and the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the build.fxbuild file was corrupted.
I'm not sure how it occurred but suffice to say the easiest fix is to get a new build.fxbuild file, either from creating a new project or copying from one that works (given that its actually just an XML file)